# Is there a formula for the closed form for $ \displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{\sum_{k=1}^r k^n}{r!}$ for any positive integer $n$?

Tags: polynomials, summation

Is there a formula for the closed form for $ \displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{\sum_{k=1}^r k^n}{r!}$ for any positive integer $n$?

I tried [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) and [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Moments_of_probability_distributions) but couldn't proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a finite sum in terms of Bernoulli and Bell numbers. First we exploit Faulhaber's formula as

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^r k^n =\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {n+1 \choose j} B_j\, r^{n+1-j} . $$

Then we have

> $$ \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{k=1}^r k^n = \frac{e}{n+1} \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {n+1 \choose j} B_j Bell_{n-j+1} $$

Comment: @hypergeometric: It is a typo.

Comment: Why would this be a **closed** formula, as the OP asks for?

Comment: OK. In the second summation each term of $\frac 1{r!}$ is multiplied by the first equation which is a function of $r$, so can you isolate the two summations and replace the first one by $e$?

Comment: @hypergeometric: When you change the order of summations you end up with the sum $$ \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^{n-i+1}}{r!} = Bell_{n-j+1}$$.

Comment: @hypergeometric: You are welcome!

Comment: @AlexM.: If you think this is not a closed formula then try to come up with one which is closed!

Comment: The fact that I do not know a closed formula does not mean that the one presented above is!

Comment: In your clarification did you mean to write $e\cdot \text{Bell}_{n-j+1}$?

Comment: @hypergeometric: Yes, just see Bell numbers.

Comment: Yes, I know. Just clarifying for completeness for other readers here.